# Find all possible substrings of length n

Tags: r

I have an interesting (only for me, perhaps, :)) question. I have text like:

```
"abbba"
```

The question is to find all possible substrings of length n in this string. For example, if `n = 2`, the substrings are

```
'ab','bb','ba'
```

and if `n = 3`, the substrings are

```
'abb','bbb','bba'
```

I thought to use something like this:

```
x <- 'abbba'
m <- matrix(strsplit(x, '')[[1]], nrow=2)
apply(m, 2, paste, collapse='')
```

But I got a warning and it doesn't work for len = 3.

Comment: In the first example you are missing `'aa'` right?

Comment: Yup, because input text doesn't contain 'aa'. Well, actually, I think, finding all possible combinations of elements given lenght and then greping will work. Any ideas how to realize it?

Comment: `?combn` is probably what you are looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `combn` all combinations of the vector will be arranged by column. Splitting the vector prior and transposing the result will give the result as a matrix. It can then be combined with `do.call(paste,...)` on the matrix as a data frame:

```
mat <- unique(t(combn(strsplit(x, "")[[1]],2)))
do.call(paste0, as.data.frame(mat))
#[1] "ab" "aa" "bb" "ba"
```

**Update**

We can also specify the way `combn` treats the combinations with a shorter syntax (@docendo):

```
unique(combn(strsplit(x, "")[[1]],3, FUN=paste, collapse=""))
```

**edit**

Use this solution only if you are seeking **all** combinations. If you are only seeking a rolling split, use Julius' answer.

Comment: This can be done as `unique(combn(strsplit("abbba", "", fixed=TRUE)[[1L]], 2, FUN = paste, collapse = ""))`

Answer (score 11):

We may use

```
x <- "abbba"
allsubstr <- function(x, n) unique(substring(x, 1:(nchar(x) - n + 1), n:nchar(x)))
allsubstr(x, 2)
# [1] "ab" "bb" "ba"
allsubstr(x, 3)
# [1] "abb" "bbb" "bba"
```

where `substring` extracts a substring from `x` starting and ending at specified positions. We exploit the fact that `substring` is vectorized and pass `1:(nchar(x) - n + 1)` as starting positions and `n:nchar(x)` as ending positions.

Comment: @RichardScriven, thanks, the current version is inspired by your deleted answer; before I thought that `substring` is not vectorized over the 2nd and the 3rd arguments.

Comment: @Julius Any idea on why this acts weird around slashes? It will return strings of length 3 even when specified n = 2 seemingly ignoring slashes.

Comment: @Alexander, I'm not sure what you mean, I cannot reproduce any problems. What is `x` in your case and the expected output?

Comment: @Julius `x` is a line read from file. I wanted to search for the string "\t". I set `n = 2` but strings that had "\t" also had an extra character.

Comment: @Alexander, this is because `\t` is seen as tab; see `?Quotes`. This causes problems for `nchar` as well as `substring`.

Comment: @Julius I see. In any case I did figure out a different approach to extract the information I wanted.