# Count number of occurrences when string contains substring

Tags: r

I have string like

```
'abbb'
```

I need to understand how many times I can find substring 'bb'.

```
grep('bb','abbb')
```

returns `1`. Therefore, the answer is `2` (a-bb and ab-bb). How can I count number of occurrences the way I need?

Comment: How large is your real problem? (In other words, how important is efficiency?)

Comment: the data is small, I'm just curious if it can be realized in R

Comment: One possibility would be to go back to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35561641/find-all-possible-substrings-of-length-n and then `sum(allsubstr('abbb', nchar('bb')) == 'bb')`, **where** my function `allsubstr` no longer uses `unique`.

Comment: similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25800042/overlapping-matches-in-r

Comment: `table(Vectorize(substr)('abbb', 1:3, 1:3 + 1))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an ugly approach using substr and sapply:

```
input <- "abbb"

search <- "bb"


res <- sum(sapply(1:(nchar(input)-nchar(search)+1),function(i){
  substr(input,i,i+(nchar(search)-1))==search
}))
```

Answer (score 7):

You can make the pattern non-consuming with `'(?=bb)'`, as in:

```
length(gregexpr('(?=bb)', x, perl=TRUE)[[1]])
[1] 2
```

Comment: It does work if we grep single substring, but it doesnt if we have to find for multiple substrings and have to use loop.
x=c('aa','bb','ba')
length(gregexpr('(?=x[2])', x, perl=TRUE)[[1]])

Comment: A loop appears to unavoidable.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `stri_count`

```
library(stringi)
stri_count_regex(input, '(?=bb)')
#[1] 2

stri_count_regex(x, '(?=bb)')
#[1] 0 1 0
```

#### data

```
input <- "abbb"
x <- c('aa','bb','ba')
```