# Count the occurrence of all possible substrings and their occurrence

Tags: r, string, frequency

Given a string, I want to calculate each possible substring occurs in the string. For example, given a string

```
str = "abab"
```

I want to calculate all possible substrings and their values:

```
"A" = 2
"B" = 2
"AA" = 0
"AB" = 2
"BA" = 1
"BB" = 0
```

I have written a function as below:

```
countSubstrings <- function(string_try ="", items = NULL )
{
  string_try <- toupper(string_try)

  if(is.null(items))
  {
    items <- strsplit(string_try, "")[[1]]
  }

  n <- length(unique(items))

  counts_substrings <- c()
  substrings_all <- c()

  for (i in 1:n) # Number of characters in substring
  {
    substrings_combo <- gtools::permutations(n, i, unique(items), repeats=TRUE)

    print(paste("The number of combinations is: ", 
          nrow(substrings_combo), "for substrings of length", i))

    for(j in 1:nrow(substrings_combo))
    {
      tosearch <- paste(substrings_combo[j,], collapse = "")

      substrings_all <- c(substrings_all, tosearch)

      total <- sum(grepl(tosearch, 
                 sapply(1:(nchar(string_try) - 1), 
                        function(ii) substr(string_try, ii, ii + 1)))) 

      counts_substrings <- c(counts_substrings, find_overlaps(tosearch, string_try))

    }
  }

  return(list(substrings_all,counts_substrings))
}
```

It does what I want but it is ridiculously slow. One potential flaw I see it my program considers substrings "aaa" even if occurrence of "aa" is zero. This is popular in sequence analysis and pattern mining. I wondering if there is a faster implementation already or it can be optimized somehow. Need an R solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All consecutive substrings? Your example has some values of `0` that aren't substrings as such.

How about:

Create a function that extracts ([not just unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35561641/find-all-possible-substrings-of-length-n)) substrings of length `n`

```
allsubstr <- function(x, n) substring(x, 1:(nchar(x) - n + 1), n:nchar(x))
```

This can extract any group of 1, 2, 3, ..., n substrings

```
allsubstr("abab", 1)
#> [1] "a" "b" "a" "b"
allsubstr("abab", 2)
#> [1] "ab" "ba" "ab"
allsubstr("abab", 3)
#> [1] "aba" "bab"
allsubstr("abab", 4)
#> [1] "abab"
```

then this can be iterated over for 1 up to the length of the desired string, and a table of the occurrences created

```
substrings_table <- function(string) table(unlist(sapply(1:nchar(string), allsubstr, x=string)))

substrings_table("abab")
#>  a   ab  aba abab    b   ba  bab 
#>  2    2    1    1    2    1    1
```

Including all other potential combinations of characters is a potential extension of this, and only requires checking a list of the combinations against this table.

Answer (score 2):

I find `quanteda` package quite useful for these types of operations,

```
library(quanteda)
x <- "abab" 

ngrams(strsplit(x, '')[[1]], n = 2, concatenator = '')
#[1] "ab" "ba" "ab"

#or
table(ngrams(strsplit(x, '')[[1]], n = 2, concatenator = ''))
#ab ba 
# 2  1 

#or to get all combinations,
unlist(sapply(1:nchar(x), function(i)table(ngrams(strsplit(x, '')[[1]], n = i, concatenator = ''))))
#a    b   ab   ba  aba  bab abab 
#2    2    2    1    1    1    1
```