# Find all possible substrings of length n using a delimiter

Tags: r

I am faced with a problem similar to [Find all possible substrings of length n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35561641/find-all-possible-substrings-of-length-n). However, instead of finding all possible substrings on a character basis, I want to split words using a delimiter such as underscore.

For example:

```
"423.A_425.A_429.B_440.A_480.C_502.B"
```

From this, I want to extract the following patterns using `n=3`:

```
'423.A_425.A_429.B', '425.A_429.B_440.A', '429.B_440.A_480.C', '440.A_480.C_502.B'
```

And with `n=4`, the substrings should become:

```
'423.A_425.A_429.B_440.A', '425.A_429.B_440.A_480.C', '429.B_440.A_480.C_502.B'
```

I tried adapting Julius Vainora's solution (see below) to use patterns between underscore instead of splitting by characters, but no luck yet:

```
allsubstr <- function(x, n) unique(substring(x, 1:(nchar(x) - n + 1), n:nchar(x)))
```

I then get as output (using `n=3`):

```
"423" "23." "3.A" ".A_" "A_4" "_42" "425" "25." "5.A" "429" "29." "9.B" ".B_" "B_4" "_44" "440" "40." "0.A" "_48" "480" "80." "0.C" ".C_" "C_5" "_50" "502" "02." "2.B"
```

What could be an alternative?

Comment: Could you add the output of your current approach? This way people don't even have to execute your code and might already spot something.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I have now added my current output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like OP only wants combinations having the same order as they appear in the original string.

```
v <- "423.A_425.A_429.B_440.A_480.C_502.B"

allsubstr <- function(string, size, delim) {
  vec_string <- unlist(strsplit(string, delim))

  if(size < 1 || size > length(vec_string))
    stop("size must be element of [1, ", length(vec_string), "]")

  if(size == 1)
    return(vec_string)

  idxs <- cbind(start = size:length(vec_string) - size + 1, 
                end = size:length(vec_string))
  mx <- apply(idxs, 1, function(i, s, d) s[c(i["start"]:i["end"])], s = vec_string, d = delim)
  apply(mx, 2, paste, collapse = delim)
}
```

Then we can do:

```
> allsubstr(v, 0, "_")
Error in allsubstr(v, 0, "_") : size must be element of [1, 6]

> allsubstr(v, 3, "_")
[1] "423.A_425.A_429.B" "425.A_429.B_440.A" "429.B_440.A_480.C" "440.A_480.C_502.B"

> allsubstr(v, 4, "_")
[1] "423.A_425.A_429.B_440.A" "425.A_429.B_440.A_480.C" "429.B_440.A_480.C_502.B"

> allsubstr(v, 7, "_")
Error in allsubstr(v, 7, "_") : size must be element of [1, 6]
```

Comment: I indeed want to preserve the order of the combinations, so this solution works the best for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We can `split` at the `_` and use `combn` to find all possible substrings and then `paste`

```
combn(unlist(strsplit(v1, "_")), 3, FUN = paste, collapse="_")
```